# При нажатии на заголовок соответствующего столбца данные в таблице должны сортироваться по возрастанию/убыванию информации в конкретном столбце

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

```
<?php
include("db_connect.php"); 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `message` (`name`, `surname`, `patronymic`, `date`, `text`) 
                        VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['surname']."','".$_POST['patronymic']."','".$_POST['date']."','".$_POST['text']."')");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Template</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Martel|Rubik" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
  <header>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <form action="index.php" method="POST" class="col-lg-6" role="form">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="surname">Фамилия</label>
  <input type="name" class="form-control qwerty" name="surname" id="surname">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Имя</label>
  <input type="name" class="form-control qwerty" name="name" id="name">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="patronymic">Отчетсво</label>
  <input type="name" class="form-control qwerty" name="patronymic" id="patronymic">
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="date">Дата рождения</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control qwerty" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Дата">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="text">Биография</label>
  <textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="7" id="text"></textarea>
</div>
 <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
</form>
</div>
<hr />
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-1">ID</th>
      <th class="col-md-3" >Дата рождения</th>
      <th class="col-md-2">Фамилия</th>
      <th class="col-md-2">Имя</th>
      <th class="col-md-2">Отчество</th>
      <th class="col-md-2">Биография</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php 

$result=mysql_query("SELECT id,date,surname,name,patronymic,text FROM message"); 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{ // выводим данные

echo "<tr>\n\t<td>".$row["id"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td >"."".$row["date"]."

</td>"."\n\t"."<td>"."".$row["surname"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td>"."".$row
["name"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td>"."".$row["patronymic"]."</td>"."\n\t"."<td>
"."".$row["text"]."</td>"."\n\t"."</tr>"."\n";
}

mysql_close();

?>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>

  </header>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/DataTables/datatables.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вижу такой вариант:

Сперва, когда формируешь таблицу, в качестве заголовка прописать некие ссылки/кнопки, которые будут обновлять страницу с передачей данных через GET.

Далее, в голове PHP-шки выуживаешь эти самые GET. И если какой-либо имеет некий параметр - добавляешь блок IF, в котором идут инструкции MySQL на сортировку (или несколько).

Соответственно, если некий GET содержит, скажем, значение на сортировку по возрастанию, то в заголовке таблицы формируется ссылка уже на убывание.

Имеет смысл добавить где-нибудь сброс сортировки, или сделать третьим типом сортировки (т.е. по возрастанию / по убыванию / нет) отсутствие сортировки по полю.

Или ещё вариант: сделать в заголовке 2 ссылки, одна на сортировку по возрастанию, вторая по убыванию.

Если фильтр применён - ссылка на соответствующую сортировку сменяется на отмену данной сортировки.

---

А теперь пример:

```
$f = $_GET['f'];  //GET данные. Первое - числовое от 0 до 2 - сортировка
$search = $_GET['search'];  //Этот для поиска по слову

        $query = 'select `fdid`, `fdsize`, `fdcolor`, `fddata` from `f3ds`'; // начало запроса, т.е. "база"

        if ($search <> '')  //Если некая GET переменная - в данном случае поиск слова в описании - имеется, то добавляем поиск слова
        {
            $query = $query . ' where fddata like "%' . $search . '%"';  //fddata - то самое текстовое поле, в котором осуществляется поиск по слову
        }

        switch ($f)  //А вот и некая вторая переменная, она для сортировки
        {
            case 1:
                $query = $query . ' order by fdsize desc';  //По убыванию
                break;

            case 2:
                $query = $query . ' order by fdsize asc';  //И по возрастанию
                break;
        }
```

Далее пример построения таблицы:

```
    echo '<table width = 100% border = 3>';  //Начинаем табличку
    echo '<tr><th width = 50>Image</th><th width = 50>ID</th><th width = 70>Size<a href = "?PID=0&f=';  //Доходим до поля сортировки
    if($f == 0)  //Если переменная == 0, т.е. сортировка отсутствует
    {
        echo '1&search=' . $search . '"><img src = "img/n.bmp">'; //Пихаем картинку "Нет сортировки". В данном случае выводится не опция, а текущий статус сортировки
    } else {  //Иначе, т.е. сортировка есть
        if($f == 1)  //По возрастанию
        {
            echo '2&search=' . $search . '"><img src = "img/u.bmp">';  //Пихаем картинку со стрелкой вверх
        } else {  //Иначе (остаётся только 1 вариант)
            echo '0&search=' . $search . '"><img src = "img/d.bmp">';  //Картинка со стрелкой вниз
        }
    }
    echo '</a></th><th>Data</th><th width = 20>#</th><th width = 20>#</th></tr>';  //И добиваем первую заголовочную строчку таблички.
```

Пример из моего старого проекта по учёту дискет/дисков/хардов, но для ознакомления сойдёт.

Далее раскручиваешь ответ от MySQL как обычно - продолжаешь табличку, вставляешь данные...

Comment: Для сортировки по нескольким столбцам (отдельно) надо создать несколько переменных статуса сортировки, например F0, F1, F2...   И делать, соответственно, несколько условий, на каждое значение сортировки отдельно.   В моём примере, кстати, обрати внимание на начало строк у условиях при построении заголовка таблички - они начинаются с чисел 0, 1 и 2 - это и есть значения переменной, кою приписываю ранее.

Comment: Спасибо, сложно конечно, я новичок просто и очень трудно разобраться ))